# How can I distinguish between LTE and WiFi antennas?

Tags: antenna, wifi, pcb-antenna

I've a LTE router with WiFi, it switches automatically between LTE bands 3, 5 and 40, depending on the respective signal quality.

I want to improve the band 40 reception. So I think the easiest option is to remove the band 3 and 5 antennas. As the propitiatory firmware provides no interface to switch or lock a specific band.

The main problem is identifying the correct antennas to remove. The device has **4** patch antennas, printed on yellow mylar films. All of them looks similar to me!

So how can I identify the band 3/5 antennas ?

The WiFi chip is **RTL8192EU**, which is capable of 2T2R MIMO, so is it possible there's 2 antenna for WiFi? I can provide internal pictures if needed.

Device is made by Pegasus Telecom, subsidiary of Haier.

**Pictures, main board.**[image: LTE router]

**Antenna on top**[image]

**Antanna on left and right**, seems like inverted F monopole.[image]

**Antenna on bottom**[image]

Comment: Maybe they are the same antenna (it's possible for an antenna to have multiple resonances). But if they were separate what makes you think removing one would affect the other antenna at all?

Comment: @Amab:  To get a useful answer, at least post the model number of the LTE router and/or pictures of the patch antenna (the mylar component with copper area).  I doubt they are patch antennas, I would suspect they are fan dipoles or similar which would mean a single antenna would be multiband.

Comment: place some aluminium foil over the antennas and see what harms the band 40 operation

Comment: @τεκ, if I remove the antennas for band 3 and 5, then there will be no(or very weak) reception on those bands, thus practically locking the it to band 40.

Comment: @DeanFranks, thanks for the tip, I'll add pictures, model no. won't be helpful, the device doesn't even have a FCC id.

Comment: @Jasen, cleaver idea !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about the *use* of electronic devices uninformed by *engineering design detail* have been ruled to be off-topic here.

Comment: That will be very helpful.

Comment: I doubt that you router has seperate antennas for each of the LTE channels.  Most likely, it receives all the channels over the same antenna(s.) It might have multiple LTE antennas, but still not have an antenna per channel.

Comment: @JRE, might be true, there's no separate antennas for each LTE channel. But is there any chance that WiFi antennas are also integrated with the LTE antennas?

Comment: There is an obvious shorter 1/4W flex stub corresponding with 5GHz and and longer path that contains a fold back to combine the two wavelength peak s11 expected from a dual band antenna.

Comment: wrap one of the antennas in plastic wrap, overwrap with aluminium foil and ground the foil, then observe the results

Comment: the left and right do not look like they are the same. i suspect that the smaller one may actually be the one you want

Comment: Thanks! that's helpful, the smaller one, you mean the one at the bottom? close to the battery connector?

Comment: @jsotola , yeah, the antennas on left are right are different in shape, I thought they're placed for the same purpose, 2T2R MIMO antennas for the WiFi.

Comment: The LTE Band 40 is 2300 and Band 3, 5 at 1800, 850.  This means that the shortest features on the LTE antenna/s will be what you want to keep.  There are likely two WiFi antennas for diversity.  You may be able to cut the longer 850 MHz dipole parts off without much affecting the 1800/2300 sections if they are on a single foil section.  Good luck.

Comment: I think this is a great engineering question. Be nice to re-open it.

Comment: @KalleMP , Thanks, the problem is solved by placing the router on a higher location.

Comment: I'll try again by trimming the antennas. And finally solder a length of RG172 coax to attach it with different types of antennas.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the wavelength-to-antenna ratio, it can be assumed that the largest antenna is for the 5 band (850 MHz), the left antenna is for wifi (2,400 MHz), right is for the 40 band (2300 MHz) and the lower is for band 3 (1800 MHz).
UPD: as written on the antenna, abbreviation RJ-PRA and RJ-DIV mean that the antenna is intended for mobile communication (main antennas). And with the reduction of RJ-WFA (maybe left right side antennas, you need to check) and RJ-WFB, it's a wifi antenna. (here is the info about antennas https://www.eximpulse.com/import-product-I-phone-6.htm?tpages=35585&page=3596)

Answer (score 0):

The LTE Band 40 is 2300 and Band 3, 5 at 1800, 850. This means that the shortest features on the LTE antenna/s will be what you want to keep. You may be able to cut the longer 850 MHz dipole parts off without much affecting the 1800/2300 sections if they are on a single foil section.

One LTE antenna may share band 40 with one of the longer antennas.

There are likely two WiFi antennas for diversity, they are also likely dual band at 2400 and 5000 MHz on each antenna so these are more likely the two smaller side antennas.

You may be able to replace the LTE antennas with a simple 1/4 wavelength element selected for 2300 MHz.  To maintain a similar band coverage a wider (like the flat conductors they have used) or larger diameter element (screen connection of a thin co-ax cable).  Trimming it to length without network analyser gear will be challenging.

Here is an [interesting paper](https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/trerecpro/2015/hdl_2072_252332/TFM_HassanDelgado.pdf) with a lot of theory and some history on LTE antennas.

Answer (score 0):

You really cannot distinguish them most of the time as many antennas can be use for both LTE and 2.4 GHz Wlan, and they look similar. The 5 GHz wlan antenna could be shorter.

If you look at the datasheet, some LTE and Wlan antenna has similar frequency response in the 800 - 3000 MHz band.

That is because a lot of antenna vendor choose to design it such that they can be use for cellular and wlan.